# No logro ajustar el navbar con el sidebar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, angular

Lo que ocurre es que el sidebar tapa al navbar, cuando se minimiza la pantalla se logra visualizar que existe el navbar, pero yo lo que deseo es que el navbar este al lado derecho del sidebary que cuando se minimice la pantalla se ajuste, tambien desconozco si estoy usando de manera correcta el wrapper... instale con npm el wrapper en angular, pero toma el efecto q deseo...

Adjunto unas pruebas para q observen como se ve... en la primera foto el navegador esta en pantalla completa...
En la segunda minimice la pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
   <div class="gr w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-collapse w3-card w3-animate-left" style="width:280px;right:100;" id="mySidebar">
        <button class=" w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()">Close &times;</button>
        
           <div class="container">
              <div class="col">
              &nbsp;
              <div class="row">
            
                  <a class=" w3-hover-grayscale mx-auto d-block" href="http://globalr.net/site/"><img  src="assets/img/GR.png" width="130" height="50" ></a>
               
              </div>
              &nbsp;
              <div class="row ">
                <div class="col ">
                    <a href="#GENERAR" data-toggle="collapse">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default j " ><img src="assets/img/menu1.png" width="20" height="20" > Herramientas de Gestion </button>
                    </a>

                    <div id="GENERAR" class="collapse">
                        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default j">Crear Proyecto</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default j">Modificar Proyecto</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default j">Eliminar Proyecto</button>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
      
        <div  >
          <button class=" btn btn-outline-secondary w3-xlarge w3-left w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_open()"> <img src="assets/img/menu1.png" width="20" height="20" > </button>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        
        </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Comparte también los estilos que afectan al sidebar y navbar para poder visualizar mejor donde se encuentra el fallo

Comment: Sería ideal que tambien adjuntaras un screenshot de lo que quieres y de lo que tienes y sobre todo el código tanto del `css` o `scss` y del `html` de la vista. Todo esto para una mayor comprensión de la comunidad. Dando el mayor detalle posible para obtener la respuesta deseada en tu duda o error.

Comment: espero q con esto se pueda entender